# "Imperviate" is it a word what can be substituted?

Tags: osmosis

Sentence:

The aquaporins allow water to pass through the membrane and imperviate any solute molecules from diffusing across.

I'm looking for a word that pretty much is the opposite of perviate or to occlude.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=impervious

Comment: Since this question is not about biology but language, it is off-topic here. I will move it to english language and learning.

Comment: It was already moved there how it came back? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347911/imperviate-is-it-a-word-what-can-be-substituted